# Python numpy array Generate Array (Month Data) from array (Yearly Data)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert

I have a array for yearly date

```
#the first value for  year 2000
#Last one for year 2001
a = [45,25]
```

can you help me to generate this result for month values.

```
B=[ 45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,45/12,25/12,25/12,25/12,
25/12,25/12,25/12,25/12,25/12,25/12,25/12,25/12,25/12]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you corretly, but here goes:

```py
yearly_values = ...  # Put your yearly_values array here

# monthly_values[year_index, month_index]
monthly_values = np.full(12, 1 / 12) * yearly_values[:, np.newaxis]

# If you want a flat array as result
monthly_values_flat = monthly_values.reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want "distribute" the values `45` and `25` in list `a` to each month. You can do this by list comprehension:

```
a = [45,25]

B = [v/12 for v in a for _ in range(12)]
print(B)
```

Prints:

```
[3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 3.75, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335, 2.0833333333333335]
```

To numpy:

```
print( np.array([v/12 for v in a for _ in range(12)]) )
```

Prints:

```
[3.75       3.75       3.75       3.75       3.75       3.75
 3.75       3.75       3.75       3.75       3.75       3.75
 2.08333333 2.08333333 2.08333333 2.08333333 2.08333333 2.08333333
 2.08333333 2.08333333 2.08333333 2.08333333 2.08333333 2.08333333]
```